# How to add jquery carousel to php cycle

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, carousel

I have this code which outputs latest posts' titles (wordpress):

```
 <!--medzio kodas -->

<?php
foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category ) {
$the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $category->category_nicename . '&showposts=10');
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
?>

 <div class="medziop">  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
```

I need that latest 5 or other number of post titles will be displayed and also I can navigate to others 5 posts using prev and next buttons.

Comment: try using cat instead of category_name and add parameter posts_per_page=5

Comment: maybe you do not understad. this is print screen of output (marked in red) http://imageshack.com/a/img534/4562/9bew.jpg . There are 5 posts And I want to add navigation that other 5 post will be available to see when click on next